# Iterate checkboxes in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm learning some of my first tkinter at the moment and have come upon a little problem I can't really understand. Basically I need to have a bunch of checkboxes displayed depending on some dictionary I have (which can be different from time to time), e.g. `dict1` as seen below. In this case each element has a `value` of `True`. Now, the code below is what I have been trying to do so far, and it actually prints out `len(dict1)` checkboxes out, but only the last one is checked - which I really don't understand. So how do I fix it, so that all checkboxes (in this case at least) is checked, according to the boolean statement of each dictionary item in `dict1`?

```
from tkinter import *

class MainPlot:
    def __init__(self, frame1):

        self.frame1 = frame1

        for i, (key, value) in enumerate(dict1.items()):
            self.CheckVar, self.C = dict(), dict()
            self.CheckVar[key] = IntVar(self.frame1)
            self.CheckVar[key].set(value[1])
            self.C[key] = Checkbutton(self.frame1, text = key, variable=self.CheckVar[key], onvalue = True, offvalue = False)
            self.C[key].grid(row=i, column=0, sticky=NW)


list1 = ["channel1", "channel2"]
dict1 = {"key1": [list1, True],
            "key2": [list1, True],
            "key3": [list1, True],
            "key4": [list1, True],
            "key5": [list1, True],
            "key6": [list1, True],
            "key7": [list1, True],
            "key7": [list1, True]
        }
```

Comment: You should move the line `self.CheckVar, self.C = dict(), dict()` before the for loop.

Comment: @acw1668, yup, you are absolutely correct. Make it an answer if you want points :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you recreate `self.CheckVar` and `self.C` in the for loop, so they only contain the last item in the for loop.

Moving the line `self.CheckVar, self.C = dict(), dict()` before the for loop will fix the issue:

```py
        self.CheckVar, self.C = dict(), dict()
        for i, (key, value) in enumerate(dict1.items()):
            ...
```